# Configure Menu Access Visibility and permission

Tags: nodes, routes, users, workbench

I have a question for Menu Visibility.  I have an entire live site in production. I am trying to build editorial workflow for my editors, other editors and approvers. I am using Workbench Access and Node Access module.

I wanted to set access permission for menu. Currently, when user create a content, he can chooses menu item from entire "Main Menu section". I don't want them to add any new page in main menu(Home page) as it will ruin my design.

Currently, my menu structure is:

**- Main Menu (Home)**

- About (Parent 1)

  - Child item
  - Child Item
- Admissions (Parent 2)

  - Child Item
  - Child Item
- (Parent 3)

  - Child Item
  - Child Item
- (Parent 4)

  - Child Item
  - Child Item

I don't want user to add any content directly in main menu(home page). I want them to just see parent menu items when they create new content and can add them in menu in any parent item or child item. but **NOT** in **Main menu(Home)**.

I also found two modules but not sure if these are right choice or not.

1) [Menu Item Visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility)

2) [Menu Admin per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_admin_per_menu)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the content type's menu settings, you can see the menus allowed, you can also set the default parent item.  You could set up multiple content types with each one representing one parent, then remove the permission to change menu settings.  That way each content type will pick the appropriate parent automatically.

Comment: Thanks VanD. Currently, my site has all parent and child items under one (Main Menu). I can select default parent item as "About" but still user can see and select from "Main Menu" as my all menu tabs are under "Main Menu". If I built menu for each individual section then there are chances to break the system as this is live site.